# Rails - FriendlyID & Ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, ancestry

I'm trying to build slugs with a custom function. The problem I'm facing is that FriendlyID is replacing `/` with `%2F` when I try to connect to the category with ancestors.

Im doing this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :set_ancestry_slug, use: :slugged

  def normalize_friendly_id(string)
    string
  end

  def set_ancestry_slug
    url = ""
    if self.ancestry?
      self.ancestors.each do | an |
        url += "#{an.title.parameterize}/"
      end
    end
    url += self.title.parameterize
    return url
  end

end
```

Console looks good

```
irb(main):025:0> Category.last.slug
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "vilken-hjalp-kan-jag-fa/vad-kan-jag-gora-sjalv/tips-trix"
```

When connecting to the category

```
http://localhost:3000/-/vilken-hjalp-kan-jag-fa%2Fvad-kan-jag-gora-sjalv%2Ftips-trix
```

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Comment: did you ever figure out your solution. i'm trying to use friendly_id and Ancestry too, I want to create nested resources.

Comment: @user2012677 - No, I had to rethink the structure :(